# INSERT INTO for JSON array

Tags: json, sql-server-2019

I'm getting text files where some columns are populated with a JSON array. I import the file into a staging table. I want to use INSERT INTO to get the file into another table with the JSON array column parsed into two columns.

[image]

I need one column named 'military_focus' and another named 'health_insurance_focus' that will be populated with 'true' or 'false'. Using this SELECT statement presents the data as I need it.

```
    SELECT
[network_id]
[network_name],
[network_type],
[service_type_ids],
JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.military_focus') AS military_focus,
JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.health_insurance_focus') AS health_insurance_focus,
[created_at],
[updated_at],
[LoadDt],
[FileNM]
FROM
[Med_Stage].[Provider].[networks]
```

[image]

I'm trying to use that with an INSERT INTO to get it into another table with the appropriate columns. I get an error that the SELECT values do not match the number of INSERT columns since I'm going from one 'focus' column in the Staging table to two columns in the destination table.

```
      INSERT INTO  [Med].[Provider].[networks]
  (
    [network_id],
    [network_name],
    [network_type],
    [service_type_ids],
    [military_focus],
    [health_insurance_focus],
    [created_at],
    [updated_at],
    [LoadDt],
    [FileNM]
      )

    SELECT
    [network_id]
    [network_name],
    [network_type],
    [service_type_ids],
    JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.military_focus') AS military_focus,
    JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.health_insurance_focus') AS health_insurance_focus,
    [created_at],
    [updated_at],
    [LoadDt],
    [FileNM]
    FROM
    [Med_Stage].[Provider].[networks]
```

Comment: Your insert statement appears to be correct, can you provide a DBFiddle that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Looks correct, please provide a [mcve] using https://dbfiddle.uk or similar. Side note: you should probably have these two columns as `bit` columns, in which case you should change them to `CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.military_focus') = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS military_focus`

Comment: Is this sufficient? I wasn't able to create the tables. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90a5cb31ede37c78a6aca51d0d03e084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the fiddle is sufficent, being able to test immediately highlights the issue.

You're just missing a comma after the first column

```
SELECT
[network_id], /* <-- missing comma*/
[network_name],
[network_type],
[service_type_ids],
JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.military_focus') AS military_focus,
JSON_VALUE(focus,'$.health_insurance_focus') AS health_insurance_focus,
[created_at],
[updated_at],
[LoadDt],
[FileNM]
FROM
[Med_Stage].[Provider].[networks]
```

Comment: That did it! Works perfectly now. Details!